# FragmentTabHost with viewpager issue in layout

Tags: java, android-layout, android-viewpager, fragment-tab-host

I have just implemented Tabs with swipe using FragmentTabHost in android. But there's an issue in the layout. When i running my application i get the below output. The swipe is only work for the below part

[image]

I Want something like

[image]

The code of XML i'm using is

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>`

Comment: Try removing `android:layout_weight="1"` on the `TabWidget` tag.

Comment: I have already tried that. It will hide the tab widget.

Comment: I think its because `FrameLayout` is overlapping `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`. Have you tried removing either one of them?

Comment: Without viewpager the Tab is working fine.